# Text search and replace

Tags: windows, gratis, text-processing, text-search

I am looking for some free Windows software which will allow me to specify a directory and a filename mask, some text and some text to replace it it with and then to perform the replacement, optionally recursing through sub-directories.

It would be a bonus if there were a preview, preferably showing a few (user definable number) of lines before and after each match.

Multiple line / regexp would be nice.

Text files are a must, other formats a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use text-editors [SynWrite / CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) for this. They are gratis, and CT is cross-platform.

- For SynWrite just call command "Search - Find/replace in files".
- For CudaText need to install plugin and call it. In "Plugins - Addon Manager" install plugin "Find in Files". Example view of dialog (on Linux):

[image: CudaText FIF plugin]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/):

- Microsoft Windows
- gratis
- GUI
- open source
- has a preview
- can replace a string or regular expression in all files in a directory

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html):

- cross-platform, gratis, open-source, CLI
- can [find and replace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159367/16704)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html):

- cross-platform, gratis, open-source, CLI
- can find and replace.